# how to align text in a page?

Tags: ragged2e

I'm writing my report but I found that text is not align in all tha page however  added this :

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Option `document` executes `\RaggedRight` at the begin of the document. If you do not want this behavior, then remove the option.

Comment: *Why* do you do this? There is a manual to `ragged2e` which you could read and which would answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

From the manual of [`ragged2e`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ragged2e) (which you could get by e.g. running `texdoc ragged2e`):

[image: description of the document option]